# How can I solve 401 error on image render?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, http-status-code-401

I'm getting a 401 error when I want to show an image.
I'm using an API that returns data related to images (description, size, etc.). Previously I use an API that gives me a token which I use in the search API to get all the images data.
Everything works ok, but when I want to show the img in my view, I get 401 error.

I understand that this happens because the URL of the image refers to another site (which has a login)
What can I do? I'm working on asp.net core 5 with mvc pattern.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using the same API that previously worked or a different API?

Comment: Im using 2 diferent requests to do this.... 1st api)i i login and get the auth-token which i use in 2nd) api call to do the search of a word, which returns me all the data. if i dont send the token as a header in the second api call i dont get results.

Comment: From where you get the image URL? you can see it from a normal browser page?

Comment: A URL connection has parameters that are after the question mark or parameters are specified by headers in the request.  So either you have to put id in as a parameter into your request.

Comment: @J.Salas The image is stored in a digital-asset-management (DAM) https://www.woodwing.com/. If im loged in i can see the image if not i get the same error 401.

Comment: @jdweng i had to add the token in the header like this  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token); and this works because if i dont give the token (that i got from the first api call) the search (second api call) doesnt work. The problem is when i want to show that img url that i got from the api.

Comment: You cannot just put the URL into a viewer to see image.  The image has to either returned by the API in the response or you have to query the URL with the parameter in the URL.  Some severs allow the parameter in the URL after the question mark others only allow the parameter as a header.  When you only are allowed the parameter in the header you have to retrieve the image out of the response.